# Protractor - TimeoutError: Wait timed out after ####

Tags: javascript, automation, protractor, cucumber, timeout

Im using Protractor with Cucumber and Im facing this issue.

```
And Right-Click on the first record Sort Pair # 
RQA\node_modules\cucumber\src\support_code_library_builder\define_helpers.js:90
       TimeoutError: Wait timed out after 8109ms
           at C:\Users\VBG5LLN\Documents\Automation Files\Automation RQA\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2201:17
           at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (C:\Users\VBG5LLN\Documents\Automation Files\Automation RQA\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1376:14)
           at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\Users\VBG5LLN\Documents\Automation Files\Automation RQA\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:3084:14)
           at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\Users\VBG5LLN\Documents\Automation Files\Automation RQA\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:3067:27)
           at C:\Users\VBG5LLN\Documents\Automation Files\Automation RQA\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2927:27
           at C:\Users\VBG5LLN\Documents\Automation Files\Automation RQA\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:668:7
           at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

I already tried many changes but the error is present anyway.

I set 60000 in; allScriptsTimeout, getPageTimeout and defaultTimeoutInterval in conf.js
(And basically in every timeout flag I set an high number).

I delete all the steps in the function and the error is still present:

```
Then('Right-Click on the first record Sort Pair', async function (){

    await browser.sleep(2000); 

});
```

Comment: Please, provide the text of the error, not the image. It helps bots to index your question.

Comment: Is that specific error associated with that specific code snippet? The fact it's timing out after 8 seconds is significant. I would search your code base for any 8 second waits you may have and see if they could be related

Comment: Yes, I have some other Steps before this and are running fine, also I searched and deleted any unnecessary wait (almost all).

Answer (score 0):

I fix the issue, in the previous step I clicked a button and wait for it with this;

```
await expect(browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(ntwrkHomeObs.applyBtn), 8000));
await ntwrkHomeObs.applyBtn.click();
```

The button is visible since the page load and continues in the DOM after is clicked just hided inside a div that is visible again if clicks a "Show Options" button.

For some reason this causes the issue.

I deleted this line;

```
 await expect(browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(ntwrkHomeObs.applyBtn), 8000));
```

Comment: The problem with that line is that `expect()` is actually a synchronous function (and therefor does not need to be awaited) while `browser.wait()` is asynchronous and therefore required the `await`. That line should read `expect(await browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(ntwrkHomeObs.applyBtn), 8000));`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, that really makes sense.